# Laravel Installation with existing Website

Tags: laravel-5.3

I currently have a website up and running, it was developed with Zurb Foundation. I developed a laravel application on localhost. I want to add the laravel app to my current live website. However, I do not want to have to build the website into the laravel app.

What is the best way to install laravel so I leave my website untouched basically just adding the laravel app ? I just want to add a login link to my current nav menu, and the login link takes me to the laravel app. Also, I do not want to use a sub-domain.

Thanks